# Removing item from a collection safely with Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I was trying to iterate a collection using `forEach` but realized calling `remove(Object o)` on that very collection was not safe and could cause a `ConcurrentModificationException`. This is what I was trying to do:

```
public void removeMatchup(Set<Player> players) {
        predefinedMatchups.stream().filter(m -> m.getPlayers().equals(players)).forEach(m -> predefinedMatchups.remove(m));
}
```

So I had it changed to this:

```
public void removeMatchup(Set<Player> players) {
    Iterator<Matchup> iterator = predefinedMatchups.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext())
        if (iterator.next().getPlayers().equals(players))
            iterator.remove();
}
```

I really like how concise streams are, that's why I am reworking my whole project to include Java 8's new features.

Is there a workaround for this problem where I could use streams while performing safe deletions?

Comment: What did you mean under the "safe? Do you not want to get the ConcurrentModificationException while you actually using only one thread for removing or you meant a thread-safe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `Set` is `Collection` we can use `removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter)` method (for instance default one internally uses `Iterator` and its `remove` method just like in your second example).

```
409  default boolean removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter) {
410      Objects.requireNonNull(filter);
411      boolean removed = false;
412      final Iterator<E> each = iterator();
413      while (each.hasNext()) {
414          if (filter.test(each.next())) {
415              each.remove();
416              removed = true;
417          }
418      }
419      return removed;
420  }
```

So your code can look like:

```
public void removeMatchup(Set<Player> players) {
    predefinedMatchups.removeIf(m -> m.getPlayers().equals(players));
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to hook up a trigger if an item (or items) is indeed removed, how could I do it? In my case, if an item is removed from the collection, I'd need to update another different collections as a consequence. Can it still be done with Java 8 or should I fall back to my original solution?

Comment: @dabadaba Lambda can contain many expressions, one of them could be adding item which you are removing. So you could try something like `removeIf(m->{boolean result = m.getPlayers().equals(players); if (result) otherCollection.add(m); return result;})`.

Comment: I guess it's the value of each `result` returned what actually makes the `removeIf` method trigger the item deletion or not, am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes. As you see in updated answer removal is based on result of `Predicate#test` and lambda provides body for that `test` method. So solution in my comment will first add to `otherCollection` element which will later be removed.

Comment: @Pshemo: adding to another collection inside `removeIf` is somehow doing it backward. Then, it’s much simpler to do `Set<…> toRemove = orig.stream().filter(…).collect(toSet()); orig.removeAll(toRemove);`. Besides that, it doesn’t matter whether the `default` implementation uses an `Iterator` as every collection can override it. All that matters, is the *contract* of that method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

[removeIf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
public void removeMatchup(Set<Player> players) {
        predefinedMatchups.removeIf(
            value-> players.conainsAll(value.getPlayers())
        );
}
```